# How do you stop WiX from passing ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" when executing MSI files in a chain?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7, burn

In "Bundle.wxs" I have a "chain" with "MsiPackage"s that are applied in sequence. When the WiX engine applies every MSI file it apparently passes ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" which prevents the MSI entry from appearing in Windows "Add/Remove Program" control panel but I actually want each MSI in the chain to appear there.

```
<Chain>  
<MsiPackage SourceFile="myproduct_1.0.0.0.msi"</MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

This is the log entry:

```
[01A4:0A94][2013-11-05T18:04:07]i301: Applying execute package: myproduct_1.0.0.0.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}v1.0.0.0\myproduct_1.0.0.0.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Visible attribute on the MsiPackage element to "yes".